# How to add shadow cljs watcher on js directory in a re-frame app?

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame, shadow-cljs

I have created a basic re-frame app using the template `lein new re-frame my-proj`.  This particular project is interfacing with a framework ([ecsy](https://github.com/MozillaReality/ecsy)) that requires some ES6 modules and ES6 classes e.g code that is generated by the user, not simply called from cljs.  Since Clojurescript does not currently [generate ES6 code](https://ask.clojure.org/index.php/4914/support-generation-of-es6-classes), I have created some wrapper ES6 modules in my project from which I plan to call into cljs code.

After much futzing, I have discovered that it's not necessary to turn these js wrapper modules into full-blown npm modules under `'node_modules'`, but rather I can simply put them in a sub-directory of my project e.g `resources/libs` and then add this directory to `:js-options` in `shadow-cljs.edn`:

```
{:lein   true

 :nrepl {:port 8777}

 :builds {:app {:target          :browser
                :output-dir      "resources/public/js/compiled"
                :asset-path      "/js/compiled"
                :modules         {:app {:init-fn re-pure-ecs-simple.core/init
                                        :preloads [devtools.preload]}}
                :devtools        {:http-root    "resources/public"
                                  :http-port    8280}
                ;;add this
                :js-options {:js-package-dirs ["node_modules" "resources/libs"]}}}}
```

So everything works fine now, but the only problem is if I edit any of the js files in '`resources/public'` the `lein.bat dev` compiler doesn't detect the changes.  I can go in and make a mock change to a '.cljs' file, which *does* cause the compiler to re-compile, but it still doesn't pick up on the changes made to the '.js' file (or '.mjs' file).  I have to kill, via ctrl-c, the compiler and re-start it to get the change propagated.  Unfortunately, this takes about 15 seconds to compile since it's a full compile.

I tried adding `'resources/libs'` to my `'project.clj'`:

```
:source-paths ["src/clj" "src/cljs" "resources/libs"]
```

to no avail.

I also tried deleting the compiled js files from `<my_proj-dir>/resources/public/js/compiled/cljs-runtime`:

```
rm 'module$node_modules$systems.js' 'module$node_modules$systems.js.map'
```

In this case, the compiler does re-generate the files (upon doing a mock .cljs change), but it still uses the prior version e.g. it must be using a cached version.

Is there a way I can add a watcher to this js directory so I can do incremental builds?  There's obviously a watcher on the 'src/cljs' directory already.  I have consulted the [shadow-cljs user gd.](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html) but honestly, it's a little overwhelming.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of actual example code you are trying to integrate? It is very difficult to reconstruct what you are trying to do. It seems like you are making this way more complicated that it needs to be. You almost certainly should not be using a "fake" `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Basically I’m trying to implement this example from the ecsy github site https://github.com/MozillaReality/ecsy/tree/dev/examples/ball-example/babylon  
I’m trying to “port” it to pure cljs as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the directions for [requiring local .js](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_requiring_js) in the User's Guide.

Basically you put the `.js` files into the same folder as your `.cljs` file and then just require it via `(:require ["./foo.js" :as foo])`. No additional config required.

Comment: I tried this previously and it partially worked.  Yes, using this method I can get the .cljs file to load the pure js modules (and they get re-compiled upon change), but in this example note that one of the pure js modules (systems.mjs) is referring to the other pure js module (components.mjs).  Whenever I used a referenced Component object in systems.js built with shadow-cljs I got error 'ExceptionInfo: failed to convert sources'.  I think it has to do with the 'name mangling' of the modules(?)  The 'fake node_modules" method doesn't have this problem, which is why I used it and seems to work